# Java Garbage Collection - New Threshold

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I assume that the objects in Young Generation must survive 15 minor GC (max 15) before promoted to the Old Generation or Tenured Generation.

What does new threshold mean and how does it affect the JVM young generation GC, or minor GC?

Does it mean that Young Generation is not large enough in order for the JVM to perform 15 GC on the objects?

In the example below, the new threshold is 10. Does it mean that I have to increase the heap size, or particularly on the young generation?

```
Desired survivor size 121634816 bytes, new threshold 10 (max 15)
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.004921 major_cost: 0.047628 mutator_cost: 0.947450 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 330899520 free_space: 1115684864 old_eden_size: 419430400 desired_eden_size: 436207616
AdaptiveSizePolicy::survivor space sizes: collection: 28 (125829120, 113246208) -> (125829120, 121634816) 
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 28 
[PSYoungGen: 421856K->10080K(532480K)] 785165K->373389K(1269760K), 0.0312765 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2018-07-04T02:09:01.886+0800: 359.263: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 4587536  promoted: 0  overflow: false
AdaptiveSizeStart: 359.286 collection: 29 
  avg_survived_padded_avg: 111951304.000000  avg_promoted_padded_avg: 43516000.000000  avg_pretenured_padded_avg: 41.070663  tenuring_thresh: 11  target_size: 113246208
```

Comment: unless you experience issues with the GC you shouldn't chase implementation-level statistics, it's supposed to be self-tuning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The young generation is divided into three regions: an Eden space and two survivor spaces.  Most objects (very large objects will be the exception) are allocated in Eden space using a simple (and fast) pointer bumping method.  When the pointer reaches the end of the Eden space, a minor GC needs to occur.  Rather than promoting all objects into the old gen straight away, they are allowed to sit in a survivor space for a period of time to give them longer to become garbage and reduce the load on the old gen collection.

There are two survivor spaces; one is the 'from' space (currently containing objects) and one is the 'to' space (effectively empty). Live data from Eden is copied to the 'to' space as well as any objects that are still live and have not reached the new threshold in the 'from' space.  The roles of the two survivor spaces are then reversed ('to' becomes 'from', 'from' becomes 'to') ready for the next minor GC.

Objects in the survivor space that have reached the new (often called tenuring) threshold are promoted to the old generation.

Clearly, if your application allocates objects at a rate faster than the survivor spaces can handle the GC will promote objects more quickly.  The parameter that affects this is the MaxTenuringThreshold, which is a maximum, not a definite value.

You can tune the size of the regions with a variety of parameters.  Read this for more detail:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html